# Linearization of 5D Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape, dimensions

Say I have Matrix A, defined in MATLAB as:

```
A = zeros(2,2,2,2,2);

A(1,1,1,1,1) = 1;
A(1,1,1,1,2) = 2;
A(1,1,1,2,1) = 3;
A(1,1,1,2,2) = 4;
A(1,1,2,1,1) = 5;
A(1,1,2,1,2) = 6;
A(1,1,2,2,1) = 7;
A(1,1,2,2,2) = 8;

A(1,2,1,1,1) = 9;
A(1,2,1,1,2) = 10;
A(1,2,1,2,1) = 11;
A(1,2,1,2,2) = 12;
A(1,2,2,1,1) = 13;
A(1,2,2,1,2) = 14;
A(1,2,2,2,1) = 15;
A(1,2,2,2,2) = 16;

A(2,1,1,1,1) = 17;
A(2,1,1,1,2) = 18;
A(2,1,1,2,1) = 19;
A(2,1,1,2,2) = 20;
A(2,1,2,1,1) = 21;
A(2,1,2,1,2) = 22;
A(2,1,2,2,1) = 23;
A(2,1,2,2,2) = 24;

A(2,2,1,1,1) = 25;
A(2,2,1,1,2) = 26;
A(2,2,1,2,1) = 27;
A(2,2,1,2,2) = 28;
A(2,2,2,1,1) = 29;
A(2,2,2,1,2) = 30;
A(2,2,2,2,1) = 31;
A(2,2,2,2,2) = 32;
```

How can I convert this Matrix into a new Matrix B, such that matrix B is a vector such that B = [1,2,3,4...32]?

The reshape function isn't working and I can't find anything online to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values always in ascending order?

Comment: +1 mainly for very appropriate tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the dimensions in the opposite order to achieve what you want. So: just permute the dimensions (with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)) and then linearize (with [`:`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)):

```
B = permute(A, [5 4 3 2 1]);
B = B(:);
```

If you want it in one line, use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) for the linearization:

```
B = reshape(permute(A, [5 4 3 2 1]), [],1);
```

---

If you defined (note the reversal of indices)

```
A(1,1,1,1,1) = 1;
A(2,1,1,1,1) = 2;
A(1,2,1,1,1) = 3;
A(2,2,1,1,1) = 4;
A(1,1,2,1,1) = 5;
A(2,1,2,1,1) = 6;
A(1,2,2,1,1) = 7;
A(2,2,2,1,1) = 8;
...
```

the dimensions would be in the "right" order, and then you wouldn't need `permute`:

```
B = A(:);
```

or

```
B = reshape(A, [],1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote you if I had enough reputation!